# JavaScript exception when using "Safest" security profile in Tor

Tags: security, linux, debian, client

I'm using the "Safest" security profile in Tor (accessible via `about:preferences`).

Here's one point in the description for that profile:

> JavaScript is disabled *by default* on all sites. (emphasis added)

Does this mean I can make a whitelist? Or, even better, temporarily define exceptions during a session?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a whitelist by visiting websites and change the default behaviour.

1. Visit a website
2. Click on the NoScript icon (right side near the Hamburger menu)
3. You'll find a checkbox which allows you to overwrite the default values. Check that box.
4. Now you can use the NoScript settings to allow or disallow specific websites.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I only have the "New Identity" (the magic broom icon) and "Security Level" (the shield icon) next to my "Hamburger menu" (I'm assuming you're taking about the three horizontally stacked bars?) I see no NoScript icon, unfortunately. As far as I know, I'm using the very latest version of the TOR browser (11.0.14).

Comment: Am I right assuming you're using Debian GNU/Linux?

Comment: Yessiree. I'm running GNU/Linux Debian 11 (Bullseye) Stable. Cheers.